# Regular Expressions get matches without match start char

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex expression:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"@([\w\-]+)");
```

What it does is to find matches of parameters in SQL queries. For instance for the following input

```
select * from some_table where fieldA = @FieldA and fieldB = @FieldB
```

the result will be @FieldA and @FieldB

But what I actually want is just "FieldA" and "FieldB" - without the @ sign. Is this possible in the regex itself or just in code?

Comment: print group index 1 or use positive lookbehind `@"(?<=@)[\w-]+"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lookbehind` so that your regex doesn't capture `@` in matched group:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=@)([\w-]+)");
```

Here `(?<=@)` is a positive lookbehind, that ensures your match is preceded by a `@`